# Generating all the possible configurations of a matrix with some restrictions

Tags: java, matrix

I've been struggling on this for some time and I'm really confused on how to solve this problem.
I've found something that works with *MatLab* but it's not what I need.

Here's my scenario:

```
private int[][] c = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
                    };
```

`c` is a matrix in which I can have only one value set to *1* in each column.
This means that a configuration like

```
private int[][] c = {{0,1,0,1,1,0,0},
                     {1,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                     {0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
                    };
```

is valid, while

```
private int[][] c = {{1,0,1,1,0,1,1},
                     {0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,1,0,0}
                    };
```

is not.
What I need is to generate a `Set` containing all the valid combinations for this matrix, but I've no idea on how to start.
I don't know if it's just because it's late and I'm half asleep but I can't think of a good way to do this.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways of actually implementing this. But you basically have to count from 0 to 3<sup>7</sup>, and create one matrix for each number.

Imagine each possible column of the matrix as one number:

```
1
0 = 0
0

0
1 = 1
0

0
0 = 2
1
```

Then, the matrices can be represented by numbers in 3-ary form. The number `0000000` will correspond to the matrix

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The number `0000001` will correspond to the matrix

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and so on.

Then, you can compute the total number of matrices, count up from 0 to this number, convert each number into a string in 3-ary form, and fill the matrix based on this string.

The 895th matrix will have the number `1020011`, which is one of your example matrices:

```
 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

A simple implementation:

```
public class MatrixCombinations
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int cols = 7;
        int rows = 3;
        int count = (int)Math.pow(rows, cols);
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            String s = String.format("%"+cols+"s", 
                Integer.toString(i, rows)).replaceAll(" ", "0");
            int[][] matrix = createMatrix(rows, cols, s);
            System.out.println("Matrix "+i+", string "+s);
            printMatrix(matrix);
        }
    }

    private static int[][] createMatrix(int rows, int cols, String s)
    {
        int result[][] = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int c=0; c<cols; c++)
        {
            int r = s.charAt(c) - '0';
            result[r][c] = 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int matrix[][])
    {
        for (int r=0; r<matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%2d", matrix[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My idea was to take the whole matrix as an array which represented a binary number but your solution is way better, thanks! Queick edit: what if I wanted to change the matrix's size? Is it enough to change the `cols` value and changing both `rows` and the number in `Integer.toString(i, 3)` to the same value?

Comment: @StepTNT Of course, the hard-coded `3` should actually be the `rows` variable (edited this accordingly). Then you can simply change the `rows`/`cols` variables to obtain different matrices. This will in its current form only work for up to 10 rows. But it could easily be extended to more rows, by checking whether the `s.charAt(c)` is a digit (`0`...`9`) or a character (`a` ... `z`), and coverting it into a row index as needed.

Comment: As long as it works with more than 10 columns, it's not a problem if it needs some tweaking to work with more than 10 rows. I've edited your code to make it multithreaded (I also removed the `println`s) and it generates about 2.5M matrices/second on my i5, I really like your solution :) Thanks again!